# How to change the allowed number of messages in msgsnd?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In Linux, msgsnd can send messages from userspace. But if the number of messages sent reachs the maximum number of messages, the msgsnd will block, is there a way to change the maximum? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, IPC queue capacity is determined only by the queue size in bytes; there isn’t a separate capacity expressed as a number of messages. The queue capacity is used [in two ways](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgsnd.2.html):

> A message queue is considered to be
> full if either of the following conditions is true:
>
> - Adding a new message to the queue would cause the total number of
>   bytes in the queue to exceed the queue's maximum size (the
>   `msg_qbytes` field).
> - Adding another message to the queue would cause the total number of
>   messages in the queue to exceed the queue's maximum size (the
>   `msg_qbytes` field).  This check is necessary to prevent an unlimited
>   number of zero-length messages being placed on the queue.  Although
>   such messages contain no data, they nevertheless consume (locked)
>   kernel memory.

To increase `msg_qbytes`, you can use [`msgctl`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgctl.2.html), from a privileged process (`CAP_SYS_RESOURCE`). The initial IPC namespace’s maximum value can be seen, and set, using [`/proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/kernel.html#msgmax-msgmnb-and-msgmni).